# Why does `open("~/something")` not work when I am using "~" to indicate the user home path?

Tags: python

For me, the following fails

```
open("~/somefile")
```

but

```
open(os.path.expanduser("~/somefile"))
```

works.

Why does it work this way and how can I fix it?

Comment: Wait, you know about `expanduser`, but you're still confused about this?

Comment: yes. cos `pd.read_csv("~/somefile") ` works

Comment: basically python doesn't autoexpand ~ for some reaon

Comment: Why *would* it autoexpand `~`? It's not a shell. `~` is a perfectly valid directory name.

Comment: `pandas.read_csv` is unusual in expanding `~`. It also does a bunch of other magic, like trying to automatically figure out if you passed it a URL. `open` isn't going to do all that magic.

Comment: "**how can I fix it?**" It looks like you've already fixed it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux, the expansion of `~` into your home directory is performed by the shell before your program even receives the command line parameter.  Python does not use the shell to open a file, it's done at a lower level.  This is not a bug.

[`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) exists precisely to provide this capacity when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

`open` is a rather simple implementation and doesn't translate `~` to `$HOME`. That translation needs to be done before passing the path in. There's also [`pathlib.Path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.expanduser).

Comment: For that matter, it won't translate `$HOME` to your home directory either. That's another transformation that's not its job and not something that should be done on all file-opening operations.

Comment: Right. The translation occurs outside of `open()` and in something like a `expanduser()`-esque function.